# How to make background thread signal GUI thread that all data is received and okay to let user continue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a five step Wizard type application. There is a main GUI thread, and a background thread that processes messages from a server (among other things). Once the user clicks through step 2 of the Wizard, the GUI thread fires off a request to the server to send a list of data meeting query conditions. The background thread listens for the server's response. The server will first send a message containing an integer that defines the number of records that met the query conditions. Then the server will send each query record one by one.

Once the user clicks "Finish" on the Wizard, my GUI thread just assumes we got all the messages and wraps up its processes. Normally this is fine because the messages from the server come very quickly. However, sometimes not all the messages will be received by the time the user clicks Finish, and this causes problems.

My question is, once the user clicks Finish, what is the proper way to make the GUI thread wait for the background thread to agree that all messages have been received before the GUI thread starts its wrap up procedures?

Below is some pseudocode of what is probably a very dumb way to do it, but I'm looking for the "right" way, or "good design" way.

BACKGROUND THREAD:

```
void ReceiveMessage() {
  global "ready" flag = false

  if MessageType == GetCount, set expectedCount = message.Count

  if MessageType == Data
     currentCounter++
     process message...
     if currentCounter = expectedCount, set global flag to TRUE
}
```

GUI THREAD:

```
On_Finish_Clicked() {

   while (!global ready flag) {
      sleep
   }
   
   finish processing...
}
```

Comment: No `while (!global ready flag) {` You would usually disable the Finish button until all conditional are met, or you decide to re-enable it. Likely you'l have a *spinner* and a nice message that says something like, *"The hamsters are slow today, please wait"* Additionally, this would also be IO and so you would not need to use a background thread, and likely want to use the *async and await* pattern

Comment: @TheGeneral, unfortunately this is a very large, mature, legacy application, and I can't really modify the design or get rid of the background thread. I just need to make sure the GUI is going to wait for the background thread.

Comment: @MAR - GUIs are terrible at waiting for anything. Normally you just disable the `Finish` button until the requests are done.

Comment: The logic executed by the background thread should be split into several `Task` objects. Then the UI elements simply call them in the async/await pattern. Such conversion should be much easier than fighting against the threads and trying to synchronize. One simple example is https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-replace-backgroundworker-with-async-await-and-tasks-80d7c8ed89dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the same as TheGeneral, except I'm using ManualResetEvent and waiting in a button click handler using Async/Await:

```
private ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn2.Enabled = false;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // ... long running tasks in here ...
        Thread.Sleep(15000);

        // signal the app that it's complete
        mre.Set();
    });
}

private async void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnFinish.Enabled = false;
    await Task.Run(() => {
        mre.WaitOne();
    });
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Given your limitations, you might just need an [AutoResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netcore-3.1) or similar to signal completion, it's better than using a while loop chewing up pesky cpu cycles

> Represents a thread synchronization event that, when signaled, resets
> automatically after releasing a single waiting thread.

**Example**

```
var resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

Task.Run(() =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("Task is waiting");
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   Console.WriteLine("Calling Set");
   resetEvent.Set();
});

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for sync");
resetEvent.WaitOne();
Console.WriteLine("yehaa");
```

**Output**

```
Waiting for sync
Task is waiting
Calling Set
yehaa
```

In short, the idea is create the Reset Event, when all the conditions are met call `Set`. At any point, call `WaitOne` to block the main thread (maybe on finish click). This will have the affect of waiting for your background task to finish, and will also give the desired results if the tasks finishes first.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! I marked the other solution as the "answer" just because I ended up using the ManualReset rather than Auto.